# System image building in Julia

Tags: compilation, julia, gadfly

I'm trying to compile a custom system image of Julia to speed up the loading of some libraries, specially Gadfly. I tried [the docs tutorial](http://web.mit.edu/julia_v0.3.11/.julia-483dbf5279.amd64_ubuntu1404/share/julia/doc/_build/html/devdocs/sysimg.html) but Julia complains about undefined paths (it makes me require every single library) and after linking all of them about undefined variables `STDOUT` and `STDERR`. If I don't use a `userimg.jl` file the compilation works perfectly.

I first tried a `userimg.jl` file with only

```
include("/home/clavero/.julia/v0.4/Gadfly/src/Gadfly.jl")
```

but it complained about libraries not in path, with error messages like

```
Base.ArgumentError(msg="Codecs not found in path")
```

so I started including about 30 libraries in the correct order only to arrive at the errors about `STDERR` and `STDOUT`.

I'm running Julia as root to have write permission in the needed files, and runing in the root REPL `homedir()` gives me `/root`, so I suspect is a path problem.

How can I generate a custom image with Gadfly in it? Did I follow the guide wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Because julia 0.4 supports package precompilation, for me loading Gadfly (with `using Gadfly`) is not too bad, certainly not as big of a problem as the JIT-delay in generating the first plot. So simply building in Gadfly via `userimg.jl` won't help much.

However, you could add precompile statements to eliminate the delay. The following may be helpful:

- https://github.com/timholy/SnoopCompile.jl
- https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl/pull/673
- http://julia-programming-language.2336112.n4.nabble.com/Precompilation-and-functions-with-keyword-arguments-td32038.html